# Naming relationship aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model

Sometimes it is pretty easy to find very natural concept to represent relationship, for example Person and Team can be connected by Membership, but occasionally it is not so easy and the concept might seem like so artificial. So is there any strategy to find or name these kind of relationships?

Comment: I wish this had gotten more comments. I'm struggling with multiple instances of this at the moment. What I don't care for the few suggestions, is you just end up repeating type names to represent the aggregation: TypeA_TypeB_TypeC

Answer (score 1):

Naming often is the hardest part of software engineering.

I like your example of `Membership`, and I'd eloborate on some (for me) underlying reasoning.

First I describe the relationship in a plain-english sentence like "Person_X is member of Team_Y". And then, to follow the class-naming convention that classes should be named by nouns, `Membership` is the natural choice for a noun derived from that sentence (or `PersonTeamMembership` if other membership types are of interest too).

And if it's too hard to find a good noun, I'd resort to using the whole sentence like in `RelationNamedIsMemberOf`,

I'd strongly recommend against using names like `Person_to_Team` as that doesn't tell you whether it's membership, leadership, support, hatred or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think it is bad practice to use Map-object to represent relationship in the case when relationship is more technical than a real domain concept? I am not sure, what advantage it gives to me if I make an own class to relationship than use Map...

Comment: Btw, is it a bad habit to reuse the identity value object of aggregate root as a identity of the relationship object?

Comment: @Toni I'd recommend to ask these two questions on their own, they're not so closely related to the naming topic, and deserve more background information than possible in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I usually name a 1:1 relationship between `X` and `Y` as `X_to_Y`, or `X_of_Y`, etc. If it's 1:n, it could also be `X_to_Ys` or `Xs_for_Y`, etc.

(OTOH, in a database it stays singular only, as all my table names.)

Comment: What I don't like about that naming is that it doesn't tell what kind of relationship is meant. Does e.g. `Person_to_Person` describe friends, siblings, parent/child relation or what?

Comment: If you have many relationships of different nature, you can have `Person_friend_of_Person` or whatnot. I talked about a case where a nice domain-specific name is not available.

Comment: With `Person_friend_of_Person` I can fully agree. I'd only recommend to use that naming style consistently from the beginning, even if you now have just one relationship nature in mind.